# Pass query strings to jQuery load

Tags: jquery, ajax, query-string

I have a page that contains datat loaded using jQuery.load() depending on the user's selected filter, either by city or by category or both.

I have the two filters in a dropdown box and was able to make it work using onchange events:

```
$('#filter1').change(function() { show_content(); });
$('#filter2').change(function() { show_content(); });

function show_content() {
    var city = encodeURIComponent($('#filter1').val());
    var category = encodeURIComponent($('#filter2').val());
    $('#div').load("feed.php?city="+city+"&category="+category);
}
```

The above now works.

The issue is how do I make it work so that the page can also handle query strings?

```
www.example.com/?city=City&category=Category
```

or is there some other way to implement this without creating a duplicate page?

**UPDATE:**

Using code from another stack user:

```
var qs = (function(a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        var p=a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'));
```

Then:

```
// If querystring is undefined use the value of select filter
// and if blank list all items
var city = (!qs['city']) ? $('#filter1').val() : qs['city'];
```

the above works fine but when the url already has the query, selecting one of the dropdown filters no longer work.

Comment: is your question how to use query string in javascript

Comment: yes, but also be able to use the select filters which are on the page

Answer (score 0):

here is a way to implement a java-script to a get a query string

```
   function getQuerystring(key, default_)
    {
      if (default_==null) default_="";
      key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
      var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
      var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
      if(qs == null)
        return default_;
      else
        return qs[1];
    }
```

so in your case you can use something like

> www.example.com/?city=City&category=Category

```
var city = getQuerystring('city');
var category = getQuerystring('category');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes, I tried the same thing as well, but once the query strings are attached to the URL, the dropdown filters on the page no longer work, how do i make it so that when on the actual page, the dropdown filters take precedence? Since I only need the query string to link from external sites (e.g. FB tabs).